# Displace modifier does not work as described

Tags: modifiers

I am teaching Blender to basic ans advanced students & I am using the book BlenderBasics_4thEdition2011.pdf, by James Chronister in my class. That book can be found at http://www.cdschools.org/

In chapter 12 this modifier is described as below:

[image]

Neither me nor my students can make the basic cube look like the above.  Can you help?

Comment: You need to add subdivision surface modifier to the cube first.

Comment: directly from that extract: "Create an object with many vertices", the default cube has only 6 faces and 8 vertices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start wit your cube, enter *Edit Mode* (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and subdivide it like 10 times so you **have many vertices**. (<kbd>W</kbd>).

Exit edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>).

Add a **displace modifier**.

Set the **Texture** for to be used by the displace modifier.

[image]